# How to fetch and display JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components, render

I'm currently practicing fetching data and displaying it in React. When I use my method, for some reason it displays only first object instead of the whole page. May someone please assist me to figure out why it doesn't display all of the object? Thank you very much!

```
import React from "react";

export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    crypto: null,
    newArray: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/prices?key=(MYKEY)";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ crypto: data[0], loading: false });
  }



  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.crypto) {
      return <div>Something went wrong</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.crypto.currency}</div>
        <div>{this.state.crypto.price}</div>
        <div>
        {this.state.newArray.map(p) => (
              <div key={p}>
                <div>{p.currency}</div>
                <div>{p.price}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are assigning only one data in state.  this.setState({ crypto: data[0], loading: false });

Comment: Use this.setState({ crypto: data[0], loading: false, newArray: data });

Comment: you are displaying data on page using newArray array. But there is no data at all when component is rendering. You have to push data in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/prices?key=(MYKEY)";
const response = fetch(url);

response.then(res => res.json()).then(jsonData => console.log('Response', jsonData)).catch(error => console.log('Error', error));
```

You can assign jsonData to state: for example:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  'crypto': data[0],
  'loading': false,
  'newArray': [...this.state.newArray, {...data}]
})
```

I have no idea how it should lookslike. I mean your json. What data is there? Type of data (Arrays, Objects...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `newArray` while getting api response in `componentDidMount`.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/prices?key=(MYKEY)";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ crypto: data[0], newArray: data, loading: false 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.setState` method has a problem. when `setState` code has execute. attribute, `newArray` disappears. i think you should fix like this.

```
let tmp = this.state.newArray
tmp.push(this.state.crypto)
this.setState({ crypto: data[0], newArray: tmp, loading: false });
```